# R not working after installing Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, r, citrix

My R installation is no longer working after installing Citrix Receiver on Ubuntu 22.04.
The Citrix installation comes from [here](https://downloads.citrix.com/21035/icaclient_22.7.0.20_amd64.deb?__gda__=exp=1660263280%7Eacl=/*%7Ehmac=5585b994b6b54b16a93dc33215ce8cfb057041f3569604889484947b06eb89cd)

After installing Citrix, I can type `R` into my terminal, but nothing happens (no warning message even).

Out of ideas of what could be interfering with launching R after Citrix is installed.

Comment: This is a question answer site. Please do not put the answer (solution) inside the question. You are always welcome to write your own answer. There is a button for that. Look below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the setup you are asked whether or not you want to install the app protection component. Choose "no" and reboot.
After that my R worked fine.

Comment: I figured out the same thing, @Jan-Fr. Except it is not necessary to install it using the tarball (in my experience). Just important that it is not installed with the app protection component.